# Can you use a base's ability twice by returning it to your hand with Mega Mech?

Tags: star-realms

I'm playing the card version (not online) of Star Realms. So here is how I believe you could play things out. Is this legal or not?

1. Play a base from your hand such as "Fighter Base" [image: Fighter Base]
2. Use the base ability and force an opponent to discard a card
3. Play "Mega Mech" from your hand [image]
4. Use it's first ability and return "Fighter Base" to your own hand
5. Play "Fighter Base" again
6. Use "Fighter Base"'s first ability to force your opponent to discard another card.

Would this be ok? I can't seem to find a rule either allowing or denying this.

Edit: I forgot to mention that there would be another Star Empire base or ship in play so that you could activate the ability on "Fighter Base"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that would be a valid move as far as I can see (as long as you had another Star Empire card in play to trigger the ability of the Fighter Base).

While there are no rules anywhere that I have found to support or reject this exact scenario, the [official Crisis expansion announcement](http://www.starrealms.com/announcing-star-realms-expansion-crisis/) indicates that it is possible:

> Here we see **Mega Mech**, one of the few cards in the game with the awesome ability to return bases to hand. Sometimes you’ll want to bounce your opponent’s Outpost to let your fleet slam in for big damage, but even cooler is returning one of your own powerful bases to hand so you can play it again!

Comment: Awesome thanks, didn't see that announcement. Also, yes I forgot to include that there would be another Star Empire card in play.

Comment: I can confirm that it works this way in the app as well. Also, if you don't trigger base abilities second time, what is Mega Mech ability even good for?

Comment: @Deo, I figured if this didn't work, it would only be good to bounce enemy bases so damage would go directly to them instead of to an outpost. But this would make the card pretty bad, so I wanted to confirm.

Comment: @IronWilliamCash this is indeed a possible use and I have done this, but it's a marginal use-case. Most of the time it's better to destroy bases.